# Node crypto Error: error:0409A06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:data too large for key size

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt a string which has length of 2224.

I generated a key pair with following code.

```js
let key = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
            modulusLength: 2048,
            publicKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'spki',
                format: 'pem',
            },
            privateKeyEncoding: {
                type: 'pkcs8',
                format: 'pem',
            },
        })
```

Now i am trying to encrypt the string of length 2224

```js
let str = "..." // length: 2224

crypto.publicEncrypt(publicKey, Buffer.from(str))
      .toString('base64')
```

but i am getting this error:

```
Error: error:0409A06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:data too large for key size   
      at Object.publicEncrypt (node:internal/crypto/cipher:79:12)
      at Function.encrypt (file:///C:/Users/hrish/Documents/cp/ew/ew-sdk-node/src/lib/encryption.js:28:20)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
    library: 'rsa routines',
    function: 'RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1',
    reason: 'data too large for key size',
    code: 'ERR_OSSL_RSA_DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_KEY_SIZE'
```

I tried to change padding modes. I also tried padding mode `RSA_NO_PADDING` which shows invalid padding code error.

Thank you

Comment: Please ignore any syntactical errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSA is not a block cipher so you can not encrypt data of arbitrary size using RSA. Using an RSA 2048 bit key you can at max encrypt theoretically 2048 bit = 256 bytes. Encrypting a string of length 2224 which has at least 2224 bytes (or depending on the used encoding and characters up to 4448 bytes) using RSA is impossible.

If you want to encrypt data using RSA use hybrid encryption:

1. Generate a random AES key
2. Encrypt the data using the generated AES key
3. Encrypt the generated AES key using RSA
4. Save the encrypted RSA output and the AES encrypted data